# After capturing image camera save button is not responding

Tags: android, performance, mobile, sdk

I have an application where my app using the camera to capture photos. Its working fine in all types of handsets excepts "mi" and few mobiles of "Lenovo". Situation is like that, after capturing the image the save image button in camera is not working. There is no permission error. Cause its working on other handsets fine. Only in all mi phones and some lenovo phones having this kind of troubles. Advance Thanks.

Comment: Put the camera capture code . with manifest permissions.

Comment: please show us some code that you have tried